# How can I know the space left in a pdf page?

Tags: python, django, weasyprint

I have a pdf with 3 sections and I had to add a page break for each section but now I have to know if the section 3 is smaller and can go into in the same page with section 2, but the tricky part is if section 3 is more than the space left in the page after section 2 I have to add the page-break.

What I mean is if I can know where section 2 ends in a page and if I can know the space left in that page, and in the space left can section 3 be.

The actual is that section 3 goes after section 2 and when section 3 is longer than the space left for section 2, it does in that way.

I expected if section 3 is longer than the space left in the page after section 2 should be a page break, if not so section 3 should go after section 2 on the same page.